# Does Magical Knack affect caster level in terms of Magus Arcana Prerequisites?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

> **Magical Knack**
>   Benefit: Pick a class when you gain this trait—your caster level in
>   that class gains a +2 trait bonus as long as this bonus doesn't raise
>   your caster level above your current Hit Dice.

Do I interpret this correctly that as a Barbarian 2 / Magus 4, I can select Magus Arcana that requires **Magus 6**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Magical Knack can raise the magus's magus *caster level*, but the trait doesn't then raise the magus's *magus* level

[Magus arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana) have prerequisites that must be met, and many times this prerequisite is listed as, for example, *Magus 9*, like for the magus arcana [accurate strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/accurate-strike-ex). This is the minimum magus level a creature must have to pick the arcana. The trait [Magical Knack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-knack) **only** increases a creature's *caster level* for the picked class, not a creature's effective level for the *whole* class.

This means a level 4 magus—even one with the Magical Knack (magus)—can only meet the magus arcana prerequisites of magus arcana that *don't* have a prerequisite of magus level 5 or higher, like [arcane accuracy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/arcane-accuracy-su) or [arcane cloak](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/arcane-cloak-su).

Comment: Yeah, it was too good to be true :-D